# How to get child control from parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using RadRibbon view.In my Ribbonview some tabs are there.When Click on a tab a usercontrol will load dynamically.Inside this tab there is a ribbon group with a button.When click this button in the group I am trying to make visible a panel in the usercontrol.But I didn't get the panel from the group button click.How can we get childcontrol(in the usercontor) from the parent window?Can anyone help?

Thankd in advance

Here is my xaml code

```
 <telerik:RadRibbonTab x:Name="rtbDevice" Cursor="Hand" Header="Devices" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,1,0,0" >

               <telerik:RadRibbonGroup  Header="Actions" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,-3" Height="95" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" DataContext="DeviceViewModel">

                   <telerik:RadRibbonButton LargeImage="/Images/add-user.png"  Name="btnAddNewDevice" Command="{Binding ElementName=uctrlDeviceList, Path=DataContext.ShowPanelCmd}" 
                                           Size="Large" Text="New" Width="70" Cursor="Hand"

                                            >
                   </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
                   <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,-5">
                       <telerik:RadRibbonButton CollapseToSmall="WhenGroupIsMedium"  
                                           SmallImage="/Images/Edit.png" Cursor="Hand"
                                           telerik:ScreenTip.Description="Select  datagrid row  and click edit"
                                           telerik:ScreenTip.Title="Edit" Command="{Binding EditDeviceCommand}" 
                                           Text="Edit" Height="19" />
                       <telerik:RadRibbonButton CollapseToSmall="WhenGroupIsMedium" Margin="0,4,0,0"
                        SmallImage="/Images/Duplicate.png" Cursor="Hand" 
                        telerik:ScreenTip.Description="Copy the selection and put it on the Clipboard."
                        telerik:ScreenTip.Title="Duplicate"
                        Text="Duplicate" Height="22" />
                       <telerik:RadRibbonButton CollapseToSmall="WhenGroupIsMedium" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                           SmallImage="/Images/Delete.png" Cursor="Hand" 
                                           telerik:ScreenTip.Description="Copy formatting from one place and apply it to another.Double-click this button to apply the same formatting to multiple places in the document."
                                           telerik:ScreenTip.Title="Delete"
                                           Text="Delete" RenderTransformOrigin="0.452,0.909" Height="13" />
                   </StackPanel>
               </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>

           </telerik:RadRibbonTab>
```

Comment: In the code you've shown, where is the user control going to be?

Comment: The code only about my radribbon control.The user control is loaded dynamically

Comment: Yes, but where? Under the Tab or in some completely different place?

Comment: @galenus First I add a tab on the top of the window and under this just add a dock panel and in this dock panel,showing the usercontrol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

Comment: Your question is not related to Telerik and you can easily find answers here (such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)).